# When can you not use inclusion-exclusion in probability?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I came across this question:
Alice and Bob both try to climb a rope. Alice and Bob will get to the top with probability 1/3 and 1/4 respectively. given that exactly one person got to the top, what is the probability that the person is Alice.

The way the textbook solved it, they did $\frac13\times\frac34+\frac23\times\frac14$.

And I got that answer, but I was thinking, why can't we do inclusion-exclusion on the probability that exactly on person makes it to the top. ie, why cant we do $P[\text{Alice} ]+P[\text{Bob}]-P[\text{both}] = 1/3+1/4-1/12$ The calculation yields 2/3, not 5/12

So I'm confused -- when can we *not* use inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: You're fairly new here, and hence don't know.  You should not post unsearchable pictures of text because the site's search functions cannot find the problem.  Perhaps this exact question has already been asked and answered.  Or *will* be asked and answered.  Please typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: oops sorry! Ill type it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both answers are wrong.

Breaking up into mutually exclusive cases,

P(**only** A reaches top) $= \frac 1 3\cdot \frac 3 4 = \frac 3 {12}$

P(**only** B reaches top) $= \frac 1 4\cdot \frac 2 3 = \frac 2{12}$

P(**both** reach top) $= \frac 1 3\cdot \frac 1 4 = \frac 1 {12}$

P(**neither** reach top) $= \frac 2 3 \cdot \frac 3 4 = \frac6 {12}$

The book has computed P(**exactly** one has reached top), you have computed P(**at least** one has reached  top),
whereas  you are asked  to find out P(**A** has reached top |**exactly** one has reached top)

You should be able to proceed now to get the correct answer

The correct answer is

> P(A reaches top | exactly one reaches top) = $ \dfrac 3 {12}\over {\dfrac3 {12} + \dfrac 2 {12}}$

Answer (score 1):

You can use inclusion-exclusion to find $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

But you need the probability that *exactly* one event happens, which is $P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)$. So calculating this with inclusion-exclusion gives $P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)=5/12$, the same as the other method.

(You also have an error in calculation: $1/3+1/4-1/12=1/2$, not $2/3$.)